# license-webpack-plugin error with nrwl/nx 8.8.0

Tags: angular, webpack, nrwl-nx

after upgrading nrwl/nx to v 8.8.0 I get this error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: license-webpack-plugin: 
Please specify a regular expression as the pattern property on the plugin options.
```

I don't use the `license-webpack-plugin` in my project (`package.json`), but in `package-lock.json` I can see that it is required by:

- `@angular-devkit/build-angular` version `0.803.19`
- and `@nrwl/node` version `8.8.0`

How can I deactivate this plugin or workaround the issue?

Comment: Same issue with @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.900.0-rc.3 and @nrwl/**@8.8.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's follow the Github issue at https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/2081

Answer (score 4):

This was a [bug](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/2081) in `8.8.0` and is fixed in version `8.8.3`

A temporary workaround: set all occurences of `extractLicenses` to `false` in `angular.json` the compilation works again.

Comment: what are the downsides to this ?